# How do I close a Unix socket in Rust?

Tags: sockets, unix, rust

I have a test that opens and listens to a Unix Domain Socket. The socket is opened and reads data without issues, but it doesn't shutdown gracefully.

This is the error I get when I try to run the test a second time:

> thread 'test_1' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err`
>   value: Error { repr: Os { code: 48, message: "Address already in use"
>   } }', ../src/libcore/result.rs:799 note: Run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1`
>   for a backtrace.

The code is available [at the Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=4bb3fb9ea20a5e6b9ce37fd69e7a39ca&version=stable&backtrace=2) and there's a [Github Gist for it](https://gist.github.com/4bb3fb9ea20a5e6b9ce37fd69e7a39ca).

```
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::thread;
use std::net::Shutdown;
use std::os::unix::net::{UnixStream, UnixListener};
```

**Test Case:**

```
#[test]
fn test_1() {
    driver();
    assert_eq!("1", "2");
}
```

**Main entry point function**

```
fn driver() {
    let listener = UnixListener::bind("/tmp/my_socket.sock").unwrap();

    thread::spawn(|| socket_server(listener));

    // send a message 
    busy_work(3);

    // try to disconnect the socket
    let drop_stream = UnixStream::connect("/tmp/my_socket.sock").unwrap();
    let _ = drop_stream.shutdown(Shutdown::Both);
}
```

**Function to send data in intervals**

```
#[allow(unused_variables)]
fn busy_work(threads: i32) {
    // Make a vector to hold the children which are spawned.
    let mut children = vec![];
    for i in 0..threads {
        // Spin up another thread
        children.push(thread::spawn(|| socket_client()));
    }
    for child in children {
        // Wait for the thread to finish. Returns a result.
        let _ = child.join();
    }
}

fn socket_client() {
    let mut stream = UnixStream::connect("/tmp/my_socket.sock").unwrap();
    stream.write_all(b"hello world").unwrap();
}
```

**Function to handle data**

```
fn handle_client(mut stream: UnixStream) {
    let mut response = String::new();
    stream.read_to_string(&mut response).unwrap();
    println!("got response: {:?}", response);
}
```

**Server socket that listens to incoming messages**

```
#[allow(unused_variables)]
fn socket_server(listener: UnixListener) {
    // accept connections and process them, spawning a new thread for each one
    for stream in listener.incoming() {
        match stream {
            Ok(mut stream) => {
                /* connection succeeded */
                let mut response = String::new();
                stream.read_to_string(&mut response).unwrap();
                if response.is_empty() {
                    break;
                } else {
                    thread::spawn(|| handle_client(stream));
                }                
            }
            Err(err) => {
                /* connection failed */
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    println!("Breaking out of socket_server()");
    drop(listener);
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Please learn to create a [minimal reproducible example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and then take the time to do so. In this case, there's no need for threads or functions or testing frameworks; running this entire program twice reproduces the error:

```
use std::os::unix::net::UnixListener;

fn main() {
    UnixListener::bind("/tmp/my_socket.sock").unwrap();
}
```

If you look at the filesystem before and after the test, you will see that the file `/tmp/my_socket.sock` is not present before the first run and it is present before the second run. Deleting the file allows the program to run to completion again (at which point it recreates the file).

This issue is [not unique to Rust](https://troydhanson.github.io/network/Unix_domain_sockets.html):

> Note that, once created, this socket file will continue to exist, even after the server exits. If the server subsequently restarts, the file prevents re-binding:
>
> [...]
>
> So, servers should unlink the socket pathname prior to binding it.

You could choose to add some wrapper around the socket that would automatically delete it when it is dropped or [create a temporary directory that is cleaned when it is dropped](https://docs.rs/tempdir/0.3.5/tempdir/), but I'm not sure how well that would work. You could also create a wrapper function that deletes the file before it opens the socket.

#### Unlinking the socket when it's dropped

```
use std::path::{Path, PathBuf};

struct DeleteOnDrop {
    path: PathBuf,
    listener: UnixListener,
}

impl DeleteOnDrop {
    fn bind(path: impl AsRef<Path>) -> std::io::Result<Self> {
        let path = path.as_ref().to_owned();
        UnixListener::bind(&path).map(|listener| DeleteOnDrop { path, listener })
    }
}

impl Drop for DeleteOnDrop {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        // There's no way to return a useful error here
        let _ = std::fs::remove_file(&self.path).unwrap();
    }
}
```

You may also want to consider implementing `Deref` / `DerefMut` to make this into a smart pointer for sockets:

```
impl std::ops::Deref for DeleteOnDrop {
    type Target = UnixListener;

    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        &self.listener
    }
}

impl std::ops::DerefMut for DeleteOnDrop {
    fn deref_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Self::Target {
        &mut self.listener
    }
}
```

#### Unlinking the socket before it's opened

This is much simpler:

```
use std::path::Path;

fn bind(path: impl AsRef<Path>) -> std::io::Result<UnixListener> {
    let path = path.as_ref();
    std::fs::remove_file(path)?;
    UnixListener::bind(path)
}
```

Note that you can combine the two solutions, such that the socket is deleted before creation and when it's dropped.

I think that deleting during creation is a less-optimal solution: if you ever start a second server, you'll prevent the first server from receiving any more connections. It's probably better to error and tell the user instead.

Comment: My bad, I got carried away by the scope of the problem and posted the whole solution. I'll update the question once I'm done with implementing the solution.